# In R, from dataframe with sourceID and partnerID columns, order dataframe by partner

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm quite new to R. I have a large dataframe approximating the following:

```
df <- data.frame(
    source = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'),
    partner = c('b', 'c', 'e', 'a'),
    info = c(1,2,3,4)
)
```

For each row in the dataframe I want to get the info column from the partner and concatenate it to the source row. I'm doing this by building a second dataframe in the following way:

```
prt <- unlist(df$partner)
collect_partner <- function(x, df) {
    df[df[, 'source'] == x, 'info']
}
prt_df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(prt, collect_partner, df)) # slow

final_df <- cbind(df, prt_df)
```

However, this approach is very slow and I'm sure there must be a better way. Unfortunately I'm finding it hard to articulate what I'm trying to do, so solutions aren't forthcoming from googling etc. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Using `match`, `df$info[match(df$partner, df$source)]`

Comment: Btw, in your code `unlist()` around `df$partner` is redundant. `df$partner` has been a vector, so you don't need to unlist it.

Comment: This comment answered my question best I think, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you work with the `tidyverse`, I'd use a `left_join` basically with itself. I first create a data.frame that contains only the info about `source` and `info`. To make sure that you have only one value per unique entry in source, I use `distinct` (not necessarily needed).

Then, I join the data to the original data frame:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  source = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'),
  partner = c('b', 'c', 'e', 'a'),
  info = c(1,2,3,4)
)

source_info <- df %>% 
  select(source, prt_df = info) %>% 
  distinct(source, .keep_all = TRUE)

df %>% 
  left_join(source_info, by = c("partner" = "source"))
#>   source partner info prt_df
#> 1      a       b    1      2
#> 2      b       c    2      3
#> 3      c       e    3      4
#> 4      e       a    4      1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With **base R** using `sapply` and `==`

```
df$prt_df <- sapply(df$partner, function(x) which(x == df$source))

df
  source partner info prt_df
1      a       b    1      2
2      b       c    2      3
3      c       e    3      4
4      e       a    4      1
```

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, prt_df := lapply(partner, function(x) which(x == source)), ]

dt
   source partner info prt_df
1:      a       b    1      2
2:      b       c    2      3
3:      c       e    3      4
4:      e       a    4      1
```

On a slightly modified set `dt_m` with repeated and missing values.

```
dt_m[, prt_df := lapply(partner, function(x) which(x == source)), ]

dt_m
   source partner info prt_df
1:      a       b    1       
2:      a       c    2      3
3:      c       e    3      4
4:      e       a    4    1,2
```

##### modified data

```
dt_m <- structure(list(source = c("a", "a", "c", "e"), partner = c("b", 
"c", "e", "a"), info = c(1, 2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```